# No route matches [GET] "/auth/github"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am not able to login my app via github OAuth. When I try to login through github, I get the following error....`"No route matches [GET] "/auth/github"`. This was working before by the way.

Here is my initalizer

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :github, ENV['GITHUB_KEY'], ENV['GITHUB_SECRET']
end
```

My user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 
  
    has_many :flights
    has_many :pilots
    has_many :passengers
    has_many :destinations
    has_secure_password
    validates_presence_of :username, :password
    validates :username, uniqueness: true
    validates_length_of :username,  in: 6..10
    validates_length_of :password, in: 6..20 
    validates :username, uniqueness: true
    
    def self.create_with_omniauth(auth)
        create! do |user|
            user.provider = auth["provider"]
            user.uid = auth["uid"]
            user.name = auth["info"][name]
        end
    end
    
    

    

    
end
```

Here is my session creation

```
'''

def github_create
        auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]     
        @user = User.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth["provider"], auth["uid"]) || User.create_with_omniauth(auth)     
        session[:user_id] = user.id     
        redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed in!"
    end
'''
```

My route

```
get '/auth/:provider/callback', :to => 'sessions#github_create'
```

And my link from the view

```
</nav>
<div class= 'main'>
<h1>Welcome to the Flight Scheduler</h1>
<%= link_to "Connect to Github", '/auth/github' %>
</div>
```

What do I need to do to correct this my issue?

Comment: Can you add server log?

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth-github ? Do you have it in your bundle?

Comment: @razvans to answer your question the gem is included in my bundle. i.e 'gem omniauth-github'

Comment: @ImranAhmad give me a little time because I am not at me actual computer to run it at this moment.

Comment: Don't have a solution, but this is definitely a result of updating to `omniauth-github` 2.0 which uses `POST` instead of `GET` https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth/wiki/Upgrading-to-2.0

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just did this in my own application! Here are a few things to do:

1. Add `gem 'omniauth-rails_csrf_protection'` to your `Gemfile`
2. Change your view from a link to a button like this:

```
= form_tag('/auth/github', method: 'post') do
  %button{type: 'submit'}
    Login With GitHub
```

Apologies for the haml. And I think that should work for you. The callback route remains a `GET`.